A single objective optimization problem, but involves higher order terms of undetermined parameters due to the existence of recursive equations
The following problem of solving undetermined parameters troubles me a lot, and I do not know where to start, hope someone could give me some hints,
Given a sample data $(p_0,q_0,p_M,q_M)$, the following recursive relation is satisfied from $(p_0,q_0)$ to $(p_M,q_M)$:
$$
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
    \left\{
        \begin{aligned}
        p(i) &= (1-a\lambda(i))p(i-1)+a\lambda(i)q(i-1) \\
        q(i) &= b\lambda(i)p(i-1)+(1-b\lambda(i))q(i-1) \\
        \lambda(i) &= f(p(i-1), q(i-1), \Theta)
        \end{aligned}
    \right.\\
    s.t. \left\{
        \begin{aligned}
        &p(i=0)=p_0, q(i=0)=q_0 \\
        &p(i=M)\approx p_M, q(i=M)\approx q_M
        \end{aligned}
    \right.
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
$$
Where $a,b$ are known non-zero constants, $i=1,... M$, $M$ is a set value between 100 and 200. The value of $\lambda(i)$ is not measurable, but it depends on the values of $p(i-1), q(i-1)$ through influence factor analysis, in fact $\lambda \in (0,1]$ is an unknown intermediate variable; For the mapping $\lambda_i = f(p_{i-1}, q_{i-1}, \Theta)$ with $\Theta$ as the undetermined parameter, which function family to choose and how many undetermined parameters to use can be freely arbitrarily defined and then tried.
a single sample from $(p_0,q_0)$ to $(p_M,q_M)$
It's expected to find a suitable mapping $\lambda=f(p, q, \Theta)$, for example, $\lambda_i = \theta_1\exp(p_{i-1}/q_{i-1})+\theta_2$ or $\lambda_i = \theta_1(p_{i-1}-q_{i-1})/(p_{i-1}+q_{i-1})+\theta_2$ or $\lambda_i = \theta_1p_{i-1}+\theta_2q_{i-1}+\theta_3(p_{i-1}/q_{i-1})+\theta_4$, so that the above recursive relation is also applicable to N sample data as much as possible; A sufficient number of samples are available, $N>500$; And for each sample data, even if there is an error between $p_M, q_M$ and $p(i=M), q(i=M)$ obtained from $(p_0,q_0)$ through the above recursive relation, it is acceptable. However, I currently do not know whether there are some methods that can help me solve the pending parameter $\Theta$ in the function $\lambda=f(p, q, \Theta)$, e.g. $\theta_1, \theta_2$.
$$
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
        \underset{\Theta}{\textit{minimize}} \enspace \frac{1}{N}\sum_{j=1}^{N} ((p^{j}(i=M)-p_M^j)^2+(q^{j}(i=M)-q_M^j)^2) \\
        s.t. \left\{
            \begin{aligned}
            &p(i) = (1-a\lambda(i))p(i-1)+a\lambda(i)q(i-1) \\
            &q(i) = b\lambda(i)p(i-1)+(1-b\lambda(i))q(i-1) \\
            &\lambda(i) = f(p(i-1), q(i-1), \Theta) \\
            &i=1,...,M \\
            &p(i=0)=p_0, q(i=0)=q_0
            \end{aligned}
        \right.
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
$$
$$
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
    &p_1 = (1-a\lambda_1)p_0+a\lambda_1q_0 \\
    &q_1 = b\lambda_1p_0+(1-b\lambda_1)q_0 \\
    &\begin{split}
    p_2 = &(1-a\lambda_2)p_1+a\lambda_2q_1 \\
        = &(1-a\lambda_2)(1-a\lambda_1)p_0+(1-a\lambda_2)a\lambda_1q_0+ \\
        &a\lambda_2b\lambda_1p_0+a\lambda_2(1-b\lambda_1)q_0 \\
        = &\text{a formula of}\enspace \{\lambda_2\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_1\} \\
        = &\text{a formula of}\enspace \{\theta_1^2, \theta_1\theta_2, \theta_2^2, \theta_1, \theta_2\}
    \end{split} \\
    &\text{Similarly,} \\
    &\begin{split}
    p_3 = &\text{a formula of}\enspace \{\lambda_3\lambda_2\lambda_1, \lambda_3\lambda_2, \lambda_3\lambda_1, \lambda_2\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_1\} \\
        = &\text{a formula of}\enspace \{\theta_1^3, \theta_1^2\theta_2, \theta_1\theta_2^2, \theta_2^3, \theta_1, \theta_2, \theta_1^2, \theta_1\theta_2, \theta_2^2, \theta_1, \theta_2\}
    \end{split} \\
    &\begin{split}
    q_3 = &\text{a formula of}\enspace \{\lambda_3\lambda_2\lambda_1, \lambda_3\lambda_2, \lambda_3\lambda_1, \lambda_2\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_1\} \\
        = &\text{a formula of}\enspace \{\theta_1^3, \theta_1^2\theta_2, \theta_1\theta_2^2, \theta_2^3, \theta_1, \theta_2, \theta_1^2, \theta_1\theta_2, \theta_2^2, \theta_1, \theta_2\}
    \end{split}
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
$$
I feel it seems like a optimization problem, but since recursive equations are involved, formulas of $p(i=M), q(i=M)$ will contain higher order terms of the undetermined parameter $\Theta$ (e.g, $\theta_1, \theta_2$), i.e. $\{\theta_1^M, \theta_1^{m-1}\theta_2,... , \theta_1\theta_2^{M-1}, \theta_2^M, ... , \theta_1^2, \theta_1\theta_2, \theta_2\}$, in this case, I do not know if the pending parameter $\theta_1, \theta_2$ is solvable? What methods can I try to solve for $\theta_1, \theta_2$?
As my knowledge of recursive equations and optimization algorithms is very limited, any guidance would be very helpful for me to move forward in the current dilemma, hope someone could share some ideas on this issue, thanks a lot ~

It seems to me that the most practical way to "solve" this is using "black-box optimization", AKA https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative-free_optimization . You won't get an answer which can be proven to be optimal, typically.

@RonKaminsky thank you for providing this useful clue, like opening a new window for me

You could also apply the stochastic gradient method from machine learning, and all heuristics there to control the learning step. Note however that these strategies usually get applied to problems with hundreds to millions of parameters. So the low-dimension methods might work much better.

If you can show that the MSE function is convex or smooth in your parameters, there are other optimization methods which might be more efficient, but the methods I talked about in the first comment are very very general so I started there.

When you are talking about "a suitable function $f$ with parameter", can you be more precise about what class of functions you consider and who is choosing the particular parametric function family from that class: you or the adversary. Also, do I understand right that you are given only the beginning and the end values of $p$ and $q$ but not the intermediate ones? I'll, probably, ask a few more stupid questions about your setup before thinking of it in honest :-) Also, IMHO&E, general methods work well in routine setups, but if there is some twist, one has to think a bit :-)

@LutzLehmann what do you mean by "all heuristics there to control the learning step", could it be a little more specific? Machine learning method may be as a try, except that I am not sure if the training process will converge, since formulas of $p(i=M),q(i=M)$ contain both higher-order and lower-order terms of $\Theta$ as learnable parameters, have you seen a similar machine learning example? Before trying to write machine learning code, I feel that it would be better if can preliminary judging whether it is trainable or not.

@fedja The value of $\lambda(i)$ depends on $p(i-1), q(i-1)$ through influencing factors analysis, but it is not clear what kind of functional relationship it is, I need to fit a mapping from $p\in [10,50], q \in [10,50]$ to $\lambda \in (0,1]$. Yeah, for each sample, the intermediate values i.e. $p(1), q(1), ..., p(M-1), q(M-1)$ are unknown but they are entangled by a recursive relation, and only the $p(0), q(0)$ and $p(M), q(M)$ values are measurable. Thank you for asking a few more, thus making the problem description clearer.

OK, but do you at least have some monotonicity properties? In both examples you gave $f$ is increasing in $p$ and decreasing in $q$. Can I rely on that? Also you haven't answered my other question: are we free to choose the parametric family by ourselves or it is prescribed to us and all we can do is to find the best fit?

@fedja Sorry for not explaining this clearly, it is unknown how $\lambda(i)$ varies monotonically with $p(i-1)$ or $q(i-1)$, because the value of $\lambda$ is not measurable. The value of $\lambda(i)$ is presumably related to the absolute size of the $p(i-1), q(i-1)$ values and the relative size between them, i.e. $|p(i-1)|, |q(i-1)|, |p(i-1)-q(i-1)|$. The parameter function family is free to choose, maybe we can design the mapping as $\lambda_i = \theta_1p_{i-1}+\theta_2q_{i-1}+\theta_3(p_{i-1}/q_{i-1})+\theta_4$ and try it out.

The next stupid question: judging from your words, example and pictures, it looks like you want $\lambda\in[0,1]$ and $a+b\le 1$ (or even $a+b=1$) or something like that to maintain the ordering of $p$ and $q$, so that you just get certain averages at each step. Is this correct, or you have situations where $p_0<q_0$ but $p_M>q_M$ (or even $p_M\notin [p_0, q_0]$)?

Actually, to shorten this conversation, just post the real data ($M,a,b,p,q)$). I don't need 500 samples. 100 will suffice. I have a couple of ideas of what might go on here, but they need to be checked against the reality before I will try to implement them.

On the second thought, give me 250 and keep 250 to yourself. I'll try to figure out the function and then we'll run it against the other 250 samples I didn't know. If the agreement is satisfactory, I'll post my approach. If it isn't, I'll think more :-)

@fedja $a$ and $b$ are independent and irrelevant, for $p(i)$, $(1-a\lambda(i))+a\lambda(i)=1$, for $q(i)$, $b\lambda(i)+(1-b\lambda(i))=1$. The $p_0-p_M$ curve is always above the $q_0-q_M$ curve, the two curves never intersect. Sincerely thank you for your time and thought for this :-), it will take a day or two to collect some sample data, I will post it as soon as possible. After getting data, I'll start with derivative-free optimization methods as the preferred attempt, as suggested above.

$a$ and $b$ are independent and irrelevant Erm... Does it mean that we are free to choose them as well, or they are given to us as you wrote in OP? If they are given, they do matter (well, technically not they per se, but their ratio $a/b$, but still if you have it wrong, you'll not be able to get a good fit in general). OK, I'll wait a couple of days then :-)


it will take a day or two to collect some sample data, I will post it as soon as possible.* Still waiting... :-)


@fedja Sorry for the delay, much longer than expected to get some data until today, I appreciate your attention, part of data is here, you can try at your convenience. For ${p,q}$, two digits after the decimal point are accurate. :)

OMG! It looks like you have absolutely no idea what you are doing with your data collection! All the data you gave me can be explained within the 0.01 precision by the constant function $\lambda=0.0018$ (check yourself!), but that is not because I have any confidence that $f$ is constant, but because you gave me a single datapoint (though it might look to the layman as a long table with 200+ entries). I suggest that you stop your process of collection of data in the current form (you are getting absolutely nowhere with it) and wait until I explain what needs to be done to discern $f$.

OK, I added an answer explaining what is wrong with your current data collection pattern. I hope it helps a bit. Keep me updated. I'm certain we'll figure this puzzle out, but first we'll need to get the appropriately diverse dataset.

Also, it would be nice to diversify $M$. Ideally, I would like to have a dataset where $p_0,q_0,M$ behave like three independent random variables in some reasonable intervals, so if it within your possibilities to run 500 observations with fixed $a,b,f$ using $p_0$, $q_0$ and $M$ coming from the random number generator and recording the corresponding $p_M, q_M$,  that would be the best. If there are some limitations on what can be done, let me know what they are. But, as I said, just extending the table you posted up and down will most likely provide no new information whatsoever.

OK, it looks like it is time to explain my approach now.
First of all, with this large number of steps and $a,b$ of size $1$, $f$ must be fairly small not to have the gap between $p$ and $q$ collapse to a ridiculously small amount in the end. I also assumed that it changes reasonably slowly from point to point (we can discuss exactly what that latter statement means and whether it holds in your case when more satisfactory data is available).
Note also that there is a conservation law: the quantity $bp_i+aq_i$ does not change in the process. So the first thing I checked for your data was this property. It holds with precision 0.013, so your claim that the data is accurate with precision of 2 digits after the decimal point passed. Now denote this preserved value by $Z$. Consider the difference $u_i=p_i-q_i$. It satisfies the recursion
$$
u_{i+1}=p_{i+1}-q_{i+1}
\\
=p_i-q_i-(a+b)f(p_i,q_i)(p_i-q_i)=
u_i-(a+b)f(p_i,q_i)u_i. 
$$
Transitioning to the coordinates $u,z$ from of $p,q$ (they determine each other in a nice linear way), we see that under the "slow change" assumption, we may approximate the multi-step recursion by the differential equation
$$
\frac{du}{dt}=-M(a+b)f(u,Z)u
$$
run on the interval $t\in[0,1]$. Since $Z$ is constant, this equation yields
$$
\int_{u_M}^{u_0}\frac {du}{u[M(a+b)f(u,Z)]}=1
$$
for every row $(p_0,q_0,p_M,q_M)$ in the collected dataset.
Since the integration goes with respect to $\frac{du}u$, it is natural to switch to the logarithms and set
$$
x=\log(u_M), y=\log(u_0), z=\log(Z);
$$
Then, denoting by $F(u,z)$ the antiderivative of $1/[M(a+b)f(u,z)]$ with respect to the first variable (it is defined up to adding and arbitrary function of $z$ alone), we get a system of equations of the type
$$
F(y,z)-F(x,z)=1
$$
(one equation per data quadruple). From here I was going to recover $F$ (assuming it is reasonable) in two steps: first in some form and then, once I figure out the values on a big set and see the graphs, to find a nice form for it. I will go into the details how exactly these two steps can be done, but only after we get sufficient amount of data to check the "regularity assumptions".
Clearly, the possibility to recover $F$, and, thereby, $f$ depends heavily on the distribution of the points $(x,z)$ and $(y,z)$ on the plane. My hope was that I would get these points spread densely in some planar region and I was ready for that (I even wrote some recovery code and tested it on random functions and point sets), but when I plotted the points from your table, I got this:
($x$'s are red, $y$'s are blue and $x,y$ from the same dataset are connected by the horizontal line).
The only thing I (or anyone else) could possibly conclude from here is that the full increment of $F$ from the left to the right side of the slanted parallelogram is $1$ (that the points are slightly shaking around the parallelogram sides is of no help: it is just within the rounding error). So, any function whatsoever with the integral $1$ along each horizontal slice of this parallelogram will explain the data perfectly well. In order to distinguish between them, the set of blue and red points should be dense in the area, not just stick to the boundary, so before I (or anyone else) can possibly say anything more meaningful about the true nature of your unknown function $f$, the corresponding plot of your data should look something like this:

In other words, you should throw you initial data $(p_0,q_0)$ ruthlessly all around the place instead of moving them smoothly in small increments so that the corresponding $(x,z)$ would fill some area preferrably overlapping with the area filled with $(y,z)$.
Then we'll be in business. Before that nobody will be able to tell you more than I have already told :-) Apologies for the exclamatory marks in my comment, but when I saw what data you are obtaining (and, judging from your words, obtaining with some noticeable effort), I immediately realized that something was desperately wrong with your current approach.
I hope I made my point clear, but feel free to ask as many questions as you want if you need some clarifications.

Insightful! You discover hidden information from recursive relation, which can help guide recovery of $f$ and data collection. Before you told me this, I did not realize that the data collection settings were far from diverse. Thank you so much for such a detailed description and letting me know what went wrong with my data. Some new samples are needed, their $y-x=\ln\frac{u_0}{u_M}=\ln\frac{p_0-q_0}{p_M-q_M}$ values should be different when the $z=\ln Z=\ln(bp_i+aq_i)$ values are approximately equal, and then the $z$ values also need to be diversified a bit.

@Maxchen then the z values also need to be diversified a bit. Not just a bit. As much as you can. I absolutely do not need long stretches of data with approximately equal z values for my recovery algorithm. As I said, if you do not want to waste time on experiments providing no new information compared to what you have already obtained, use the random number generator to generate $p_0,q_0\in [10,50]$ and $M\in[40,200]$ (or something like that, just substitute the ranges you care about) independently for each observation and then you may get away with 300 observation total.

@Maxchen Any progress with data collection?
